# How to improve CSV reading performance

Tags: c#

I am reading a CSV file and saving the data from the CSV file to my database.

I'm using `Streamreader`'s `ReadLine()` to read every line and then insert it into my database, which is working fine. But after profiling my code I noticed that `ReadLine()` is taking up too much time.

**How can I improve the performance of my task**.

Please provide me with alternative options.

Performance is the Main concern here.

Comment: How big is your CSV file? Can you split it into smaller files?

Comment: This is my code :
using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
 string line;
 while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
  // inserting each row to db
 }
}
And my csv files are very big in size(100 MB+)
I havent tried splliting into small files.
My main concern is reading a line from csv and insert it to database table.

Comment: As @Barry said, use BulkInsert to insert you result in DB. You can also split your file and use the Task parallelism library in order to read spend less time reading you file.

Comment: here, we have used SqlBulkCopy only to insert the data.Then also i found ReadLine() method is taking much time.Can you please tell any other optimal solutions for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SqlBulkCopy` class for this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). It is an order of magnitude faster than individual line-by-line inserts. The MSDN page has a complete example.

You can also speed up your reads with the `StreamReader.Peek` method - [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek.aspx). Again the MSDN link has a good example.

Comment: Not going to help if the bottleneck is _reading_ the CSV, as the OP indicates.

Comment: how can i use SqlBulkCopy to insert my csv file data to database table.And my csv files are very big in size (100 MB+).

Comment: here, we have used SqlBulkCopy only to insert the data.Then also i found ReadLine() method is taking much time.Can you please tell any other optimal solutions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `StreamReader.ReadLine` is the slow part here?
I guess inserting data into a database is **much** slower than reading one line of text out of a local file!

You might try to read the file into memory in one step with `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` if its not too big.

Comment: My csv files are very larger ones as i mentione above and Can i read the entire file into memory the use stream reader ? Is this good practice or not. If so, how can i do this ?

Comment: You can read the whole file with `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` as i wrote. When the possibility exists, that the filesize will exceed your memory its not good practice

Comment: Thars correct. Then what is the other possibility to achieve my concern ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using one of the many CSV parsing libraries - you should test them to see how they perform.

[FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) is one popular library, and codeproject has [several](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) [different](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CsvReaderAndWriter.aspx) ones too.

Chances are, however, that the issue is with inserting to the database row by row.

You should read as much of the file as you can and [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to the database, instead of row by row.

Comment: my csv files are big in size..while doing the code profiling i found that readLine() method is taking much time..

Comment: @MSHAN - As I said, use an existing CSV library. Many of them are very fast.